# TextInputLayout it is possible to override the ExposedDropdownMenu?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

I have one question about `TextInputLayout`

I would like to know if its possible to override the `ExposedDropdownMenu`

Let me explain, I am using a `TextInputLayout` with

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
```

On my `bottomSheetFragment`, when I click on the field, instead to open a list with an ArrayList, I open a new Activity.

here my following code :

```
binding?.autoCompleteView?.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(context, CountryActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

it works when I click on the item but not working when I click on the `dropDownMenu`
it only change the `arrow` from down to up and up to down...

Can I do something to make it work ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: There's an endIconClickListener for TextInputLayout you can use the same code with that!

Comment: thank you a lot @MalikBilal, I found it, I have to use `setEndIconOnClickListener`